# Как разделить txt на массив по строкам

Tags: kotlin

Есть txt, состоящий из нескольких строк. Как разбить его на массив так, чтобы каждая строка была под отдельным индексом? Не нашёл ни одного примера по этому вопросу. Я новичок и, возможно, поэтому упускаю что-то лежащее на поверхности

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Встроенная функция [lines()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/lines.html):

```
var lines = txt.lines() # в lines теперь список строк
```